# WooCommerce Price Update

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a WooCommerce booking site like:

"On the single product page, the base price is $400, when the user chooses a date, the price will then be updated, for example the user chose December 1 which has additional $50 charge, the total price would then be $450."

Now, my problems/questions would be:

How do I retrieve the Additional Monthly price? would it be okay if it is from another table on MySQL?

How do I updated the price in the single product page of WooCommrce, should there be a hook that I need to use?

Comment: I dont see any problem using another table for your additional prices.To update the price on single product page based on the selection,  I would rather do the modification in the template used to render the product page.

Comment: You should write plugin or code for this

Comment: It's much easier to use a plugin like https://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-bookings/, however it's not free.

Comment: I will be hard coding the price update, the problem is that I don't know the hook for the price override hook for woocommerce.

I already have the ideas of using another table for the monthly prices.

Comment: here it is [WooCommerce custom price using get_price() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090258/woocommerce-custom-price-using-get-price-function) or may be too [Woocommerce Hook woocommerce_get_price…](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635553/woocommerce-hook-woocommerce-get-price-how-to-used-in-product-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
 $custom_price = 10; // This will be your custom price  
 foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
    if ($key === $YOUR_PRODUCT_ID) {
     $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
    }
 }
}
```

This will allow you to change the price of the product when the user goes to the cart page, modify the IF statement to include the metadata of the date chosen and you can create cases to change prices based on certain dates. I highly recommend using a plugin instead of doing this. It will be very difficult to maintain. @scriptonomy already mentioned this but the plugin is very good its worth every penny. [woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-bookings](http://woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-bookings)

Comment: Thanks for this Nicholas! Worked like a charm :D